# Wordpress menu is all one color. CSS doesn't seem to fix it

Tags: css, wordpress

I tried to change the colors of my primary navigation menu
[image] and ended up with the text and the background the same color: https://adamfout.com/

I have no idea how to fix it. I deleted some of the CSS I created, and when I'm logged into WordPress it looks fine, but when I visit on mobile or an incognito browser I can't see the menu items unless I hover.

I changed the colors in the stylesheet too, but I tried to change them back and that didn't work either. I'm at a loss. I don't know CSS or WordPress very well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained so you need to include all the relevant code, as external links can change or break over time and make the question unhelpful to other users. Please edit your question to include a minimal,reproducible example that also has the relevant HTML, so we can see what might be going wrong and be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to appearance/customize you will find a customize css box at the bottom. There you can put:

To change the text color:

```
#menu-menu-1 li a{
    color: black;
}
```

To change the background color:

```
.nav-primary{
    background-color: red;
}
```